# Using Integer in JQ map Key value

Tags: json, jq

I am tring to convert a  JSON

```
  "ideas": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "ideaID": 499,
      "ideaName": "Apples & Bananas",
      "preference_order": 1,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/ideaProfile/api/v3/idea/3"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "ideaID": 500,
      "ideaName": "Oranges and Peach",
      "preference_order": 1,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/ideaProfile/api/v3/idea/3"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to the format of map.

```
{ <id1> : < ideaID1>, <id2> : < ideaID2> }
```

When i try to use this JQ it works with String feilds , but with Numberic Feild as key its not working.

```
.ideas | (map( { (. preference_order) : .ideaName } ) | add )
```

Error i get -- **jq: error (at :25): Cannot use number (1) as object key**

Snippet -- https://jqplay.org/s/-6c0QitFA7

This is the query with string value as key...
.ideas | (map( { (.ideaName) : .ideaName } ) | add )

Answer (score 3):

Keys must be strings, so numerical values that you want to use as keys will have to be converted, which can be done using `tostring`, as in:

```
.ideas[]
| { (.id | tostring): .ideaID }
```